# pcolor map in matlab

Tags: matlab, color-mapping

In matlab, we can use pcolor to show the magnitude of data in color. I am trying the following data

```
 A=[1:10; 16:25; 86:95];
 pcolor(A);
```

It only show two rows. Why is that and how to show all those three data set? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of [pcolor](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html)

> > In the default shading mode, 'faceted',
> >         each cell has a constant color and the last row and column of
> >         C are not used.

Use imagesc instead

```
imagesc(A);
```