# Pcolor print one row and column less than matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this matrix

[image]

and I want try to  plot it with

```
pcolor(Grid);
map = [0, 0, 0;
   1, 1, 1;
   0,1,1 ;
   0,1,0;
   1,0,0;
   ];
 colormap(map);
```

but result is

[image]

if you look at the  plot you see it is 9*9 but my grid matrix is 10*10. 
what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pcolor map in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662815/pcolor-map-in-matlab) – and numerous others, e.g., [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705092/plot-a-matrix-values-as-colors).

Comment: @horchler no, my question is why the one row and column not consider

Comment: The question and answer to the duplicate question are virtually identical this one – both are clearly answered by the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
help pcolor
```

> The values of the elements of C specify the color in each
>       cell of the plot. In the default shading mode, 'faceted',
>       each cell has a constant color and **the last row and column of
>       C are not used.**

You might want to use `imagesc` instead?

```
a=double(rand(10)>0.2); a(randi(100))=4; a(randi(100))=3;
map=[0,0,0; 1,1,1; 0,1,1; 0,1,0; 1,0,0];
x=(0:9)+.5; imagesc(x,x,a); colormap(map); grid on;
```

Comment: thanks for your attention,but how I put  row and column    number beside each other, I mean set the left bottom corner as (0,0) ?

Comment: @zhilevan: use [`axis image`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) or `axis xy`, etc. to specify the orientation to something other than the default for the type of plot.

Comment: @zhilevan `set(gca,'Ydir','normal')`