# Matlab pcolor plot number of columns issue

Tags: matlab

In matlab, why is it that the number of columns in a `heatmap`/`pcolor` plot doesn't equal the number of columns in the data?

For example, using the following `pcolor` example. Although `x` has 5 elements there are only 4 columns in the plot (albeit 5 ticks). Why is that?

```
x = 1:5;
y = 1:10;
z = rand(10,5);
pcolor(x,y,z)
```

Comment: The `x` and `y` define vertices, not faces. Face colour is interpolated.

Comment: And [MATLAB explicitly throws away the last row/column](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) (matplotlib in python doesn't).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pcolor map in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662815/pcolor-map-in-matlab)

Comment: If you're only plotting a grid you likely don't need the 3-D/OpenGL stuff that `pcolor` has – try using `image` or `imagesc`.